# Reading data from multiple text files and adding indicator value

Tags: r

I have folder full of text files ( data-01.txt, data-02.txt.....data-70.txt)....How do i read the contents of all these text files and add an indicator value to indicate which file the data came from. For example

```
 Id    F.Name       L.Name     Gender Age     Indicator
 1     Sam          Houston    M      21      1
 2     Jamal        Wilson     M      22      1
 3     Joe          Davidson   M      45      2
 4     Catavia      Jones      F      23      3
```

Indicator 1 means the dataset was from data-01.txt , 
Indicator 2 means the dataset was from data-02.txt

I tried

```
data_list = lapply(my.files, read.table, sep="\t", header=TRUE )
```

Not sure how to add the indicator value parameter within the lapply function.

Any advise on how to do this would be helpful.

Comment: Have you done any searching? This certainly sounds like a request I have seen before.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this. Haven't tested it so you might need to tweak a thing or two.

```
my.files <- list.files(".","*.txt")

for(i in seq_along(my.files)) {
  if(i==1) {
    my.df <- read.csv(my.files[i], header = TRUE)
    my.df$indicator <- i
  } else {
    tmp <- read.csv(my.files[i], header = TRUE)
    tmp$indicator <- i
    my.df <- rbind(my.df, tmp)
  }
}
```

Comment: i got an error ....Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :   names do not match previous names......I tried data_list = lapply(my.files, read.table, sep="\t", header=TRUE )
this worked but i dont know how to add an indicator value parameter within lapply function

Comment: Hmmm do all your files have the exact same header?